# Tracking thread lifetime for pthread wrapper api

Tags: c++, linux, posix

I try to build a *.so wrapper library for pthread_mutex_lock/unlock that creates per-thread statistics. Problem is that, as far as I know, threads can be destroyed and new threads can reuse the thread id/process id. My question is: How can I detect that an incoming thread with a process id is not the same thread anymore? My first thought was using pthread_cleanup_push and pop to track thread destruction, but for that I would need access to the threads run method which I don't have as I'm writing a wrapper api.

Do you have different suggestions?

Regards

Comment: Can you make your API wrap pthread_join and pthread_detach too?

Comment: Probably. Will these cover all cases?